# Unable to filter a dropdownchoice in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have an object Users that contains a set of another object, Roles. I created a new panel, ListPanel, to hold a listview of the roles a User has. All of which is contained in a DataTable. I want to be able to filter on that list of roles though and that is where I am stuck. When I try and filter the Roles on the DataTable I get the following error: "Could not convert value: Admin to type: java.util.Set. Could not find compatible converter." Admin being the value I get from the dropdown.

I'm lost as to where to go from here. From what I've read you can not use a Converter with a DropDownChoice so I looked into creating a Renderer but the value that is passed into the Renderer is a String and not the Role object. I think that the Renderer was the right choice but something needs to change elsewhere to get it to work.

Entities

```
public class User {
     private String id;
     private String name;
     private Set<Role> roles;
     ......properties/getters/setters.......
}

public class Role {
     private String role;
     private int active;
     ......properties/getters/setters.......
}
```

Search Panel

```
public class UserSearchPanel extends BreadCrumbPanel {
    private static final int ROWS_PER_PAGE = 20;

    @Inject
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Inject
    private RoleDao roleDao;    

    private final UserDataTable dataTable;

    public UserSearchPanel( final String id, final IBreadCrumbModel breadCrumbModel ) {
        super( id, breadCrumbModel );
        NotificationPanel feedback = new NotificationPanel( "feedback" );
        feedback.setOutputMarkupId( true );
        add( feedback );

        UserDataProvider dataProvider = new UserDataProvider( userDao );
        dataProvider.setFilterState( loadFilterState() );

        // create the form used to contain all filter components
        final FilterForm<User> form = new FilterForm<User>( "userSearchForm", dataProvider ) {

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit() {
                dataTable.setCurrentPage( 0 );
            }

        };

        dataTable = new UserDataTable( "dataTable", createColumns(), dataProvider, ROWS_PER_PAGE, this );

        dataTable.addTopToolbar( new FilterToolbar( dataTable, form, dataProvider ) );
        form.add( dataTable );
        add( form );
    }

    /**
     * The columns shown on the page.
     */
    private List<IColumn<User, String>> createColumns() {

        List<IColumn<User, String>> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn<User, String>>();
        List<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            choices = roleDao.getAvailableRoles();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if ( choices.size() > 1 ) {
            IModel<List<? extends String>> filterChoices = Model.ofList( choices );
            columns.add( createChoiceColumn( "datatable.roles.label", "roles", "roles", filterChoices ) );
        }
        return columns;
    }

    private ChoiceFilteredPropertyColumn<User, String, String> createChoiceColumn( final String key, final String sortProperty, final String propertyExpression, final IModel<List<? extends String>> filterChoices ) {

        IModel<String> label = getLabel();

        return new ChoiceFilteredPropertyColumn<User, String, String>( label, sortProperty, propertyExpression, filterChoices ) {

            @Override
            protected boolean enableAutoSubmit() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void populateItem( Item<ICellPopulator<User>> cellItem, String componentId, IModel<User> rowModel ) {
                cellItem.add( new ListPanel( componentId, rowModel ) );
            }
        };
    }

    private class ListPanel extends Panel {

        public ListPanel( String id, IModel<User> model ) {
            super( id );
            User user = (User) model.getObject();
            addList( user );
        }

        private void addList( User user ) {
            Set<Role> rolesSet = user.getRoles();
            List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
            for ( Role role : rolesSet ) {
                roles.add( role );
            }

            ListView<Role> view = new ListView<Role>( "list", roles ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateItem( ListItem<Role> item ) {
                    final Role role = (Role) item.getModelObject();
                    item.add( new Label( "roles", role.getRole() ) );
                }
            };
            add( view );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Blah class?

Comment: It isn't a class, it's the value I get from the drop down. So Admin for instance could be the value. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using your `User` object I would suggest that you create a class that represents what you're going to filter and react upon those values in your `IDataProvider`.

What currently happens is that you're using the User object to represent your `FilterState` and wicket tries to set the String "ADMIN" to your `Set<Role>` of that `User` object.

Just declare your different filter options in an seperate Object.

Like:

```
    class FilterState implements Serializable {
    private String roles;

    public String getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(String roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}

class UserDataProvider implements IDataProvider<User>, IFilterStateLocator<FilterState> {

    private FilterState state;

    private UserDao userDao;

    public UserDataProvider() {
        state = new FilterState();
    }

    ....

    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends User> iterator(long first, long count) {
        //just some example filter logic, handled by the dao
        if (state == null || state.getRoles() == null) {
            return userDao.getUserList(first, count).iterator();
        } else {
            return userDao.getUserListByRoleName(state.getRoles(), first, count).iterator();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public FilterState getFilterState() {
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterState(FilterState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry it's taken a bit but I believe this has fixed my problem. I've just run into some other issues that I'm trying to work through to confirm. I'll leave another comment when I confirm. I don't have enough rep to Vote Up the answer however I've marked it as correct.

Comment: Thanks this was the solution.